# Don't start Windows camera wizard when connecting iPhone?

Tags: windows, iphone, usb, camera

Every time I connect my iPhone, Windows XP pops up a wizard (I think it's called "Microsoft Camera and Scanner Wizard) to retrieve photos - as if it were just a camera. *How do I stop this from happening?*

Oddly, when I connect my actual digital camera, this wizard doesn't pop up. I'm using [cam2pc](http://www.nabocorp.com/cam2pc) to unload photos from my camera, and that works fine and no Windows wizard pops up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.) Go to Control Panel.
2.) Scroll to Scanners and Cameras.
3.) Right-click "Apple iPhone" and left-click "Properties" in the popup box.
4.) Within properties window click on the "Events" tab.
5.) Select "Take no action" under "Actions."

Comment: Don't think I'd have found that on my own. I'll try it out and report back - thank you Systech!

Comment: @torbengb it should work fine

Comment: Note that this requires plugging in the iPhone in order to see it on the "scanners and cameras" screen, AND requires dismissing the popup before it'll show the Properties tab.

Answer (score 2):

For Vista:

Click the link at the bottom of the AutoPlay pop-up "Set AutoPlay defaults in Control Panel"
Scroll down to your iPhone and select "Take no action" from the drop down.