# Trying to stop iPhone pop up everytime its plugged in but control panel not recognizing iPhone

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, control-panel, picture-import-wizard

Every time I connect my iPhone, Windows XP pops up a wizard (I think it's called "Microsoft Camera and Scanner Wizard) to retrieve photos - as if it were just a camera. Very annoying! Instructions to stop this were given as:

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Scroll to Scanners and Cameras.
3. Right-click "Apple iPhone" and left-click "Properties" in the popup box.
4. Within properties window click on the "Events" tab.
5. Select "Take no action" under "Actions."

Except when I open control panel/scanners and cameras the iPhone isn't there, only the integrated webcam. The iPhone is plugged in, I've dismissed the pop up asking what the computer wants me to do (which is still driving me crazy!) and refreshed . So the computer is recognizing the iPhone, it's just not appearing in the control panel. Any advice?

Comment: If you don't need autoplay, disable that altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. It still didn't work. Downloaded Tweak UI and disabled autoplay on all drives. And I still get the popup!! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, call Apple.

Comment: Please *do not* vote to close as duplicate--the OP already tried [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/45022/dont-start-windows-camera-wizard-when-connecting-iphone/45026#45026) and it did not work.

Comment: I think that if you still have the popup there is an option down there that says `No Action`, it would do that. Other than this, try updating iTunes (with the proper care)

Answer (score 0):

```
// dummy.c --  rename the exe to %WINDIR%/system32/wiaacmgr.exe
int __stdcall WinMain(void*a, void*b, void*v, int d) {}
```

Comment: Replacing the executable with a non-functional dummy is a *really* drastic measure.

Comment: for human yes, but should be ok for a Dragon Lord.